# Meteor Range Error out of memory

Tags: python, meteor, pymongo

SO im using python to do some data aggregation and computationally complex tasks. the result is a file that is about 300mb and has about 125,000 lines.

Using pymongo, I push this database into mongoDB and get this error almost every time.

```
Exception in defer callback: RangeError: Out of memory
I20160817-15:14:16.079(-4)?     at RangeError (native)
I20160817-15:14:16.079(-4)?     at DocFetcher.fetch (packages/mongo/doc_fetcher.js:60:8)
I20160817-15:14:16.079(-4)?     at packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:509:43
I20160817-15:14:16.079(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.forEach (packages/id-map/id-map.js:48:1)
I20160817-15:14:16.080(-4)?     at packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:507:35
I20160817-15:14:16.080(-4)?     at packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:16:9
I20160817-15:14:16.080(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160817-15:14:16.080(-4)?     at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1
I20160817-15:14:16.080(-4)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
```

Each client is only ever subscribed to 500 ish documents at a time.

My theory is that this happens because meteor is reading each entry as a change, and trying to push each database change to the client, rather than something in bulk?

Is there anything I can do? Would this problem go away if this were not on the development server and the server had more RAM.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your hypothesis is a good one. Meteor is looking at mongo changes through the oplog and having to decide whether or not to publish each change to each client. Have you tried using mongo [bulk insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/) rather than importing rows one at a time?

Comment: Pymongo has the function `insert_many()` which is supposed to implement a bulk insert. There Seems to be no difference when using this or the standard pymongo insert.